# How do you call the space $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

How do you call the space $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

I also know it under the name $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$.

Topologically, $\mathbb{N}$ and $\omega$ are the same thing basically, denoting the countable product of rationals.

However, I am asking for other names, since I completely fail to google anything about $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the best I can find is $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{n}}$, which is something different.

How do you search for the stuff about $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$? Does it have any special name?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess would be "set of rational sequences".

Comment: I  second *rational sequences*. $\Bbb Q^n$ is just homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ so gets no special name. $\omega$ is just the set theory symbol for $\Bbb N$. So any set-theory minded topologist writes it $\Bbb Q^\omega$ I suppose.

Comment: Sometimes, though not always, $\mathbb Q^\omega$ (or $F^\omega$ in general) is used to mean the subspace of sequences with only finitely many nonzero elements.

Comment: I looked in Pi-Base, and did not find a special name for this.  https://topology.jdabbs.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is just the space of all rational sequences since its the set of all functions from the naturals to the rationals.

Comment: A very technical topological characterisation: $X \simeq \Bbb Q^\omega$ iff $X$ is a separable metrisable zero-dimensional absolute $F_{\sigma\delta}$ that is nowhere $G_{\delta\sigma}$ and of the first category. Proof: PhD thesis of F. van Engelen, *homogeneous zero-dimensional absolute Borel sets* @TerezaTizkova